# Error during installation

Tags: error, cli, installation

Installation fail of Solana CLI on Windows 11.

```
Program 'solana-install-init.exe' failed to run: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadableAt line:1 char:1
+ C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

[image: trying running by hand]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install WSL (Ubuntu on Windows) instead.

Comment: I do have it, but I think ignoring this issue is not the best way to go, as CLI is also offered for windows.
Thank you for the idea, though!